# What is the origin of the word "nepotismo" in Spanish?

Tags: etimología

We tend to use the word "nepotismo" when someone who has a good position into the goverment gives some privileges to his / her family or relatives. I wonder, where does it come from?

Answer (score 6):

It comes from the Latin word *nepos* (pl. *nepōtes*) which originally meant grandson and later evolved to mean descendent generally and nephew specifically.  That latter meaning is used in Italian which derived the word with the *-ismo* ending to describe the practice of giving favor to one's nephews (and later extended in meaning more generally to all family members) as a result of 17th century popes giving cardinalships to their nephews.

I'm not sure if it entered into Spanish directly via the Italian *nepotismo* or via the French *népotisme*, though, although it could have been both simultaneously.